# How can I essentially '\ensuremath' a \DeclarePairedDelimiter (from `mathtools`)?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, mathtools

I am trying to create a paired delimiter command that will work outside of text mode. I was not able to accomplish this simply by defining a new command with `\ensuremath`, so I've resorted to the use of `\ifmmode` and `\@ifstar` instead; however, the code (given below) does not run as expected. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? (I would prefer it if the command were to be defined through `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` or its variants `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP`.)

I realize it's often considered bad practice to rely on code such as `\ensuremath`, but I'm mostly just doing this for the TeXnical learning experience.

```
\documentclass[12pt, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\makeatletter
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP{\conctext}[1]{\(}{\lbrack}{\rbrack}{\)}{\ce{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\concmath}[1]{\lbrack}{\rbrack}{\ce{#1}}
\newcommand{\conc}{\ifmmode \@ifstar\concmath*\concmath
                    \else   \@ifstar\conctext*\conctext
                    \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
The molarity is calculated from \conc{NaOH}, \conc{H3O+}, and \conc{OH-}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's to keep you from telling LaTeX that `\conc` has one argument and it must be placed between your `\concmath` and `\conctext` macros? `\newcommand{\conc}[1]{\ifmmode \@ifstar\concmath* #1\concmath\else \@ifstar\conctext* #1\conctext\fi}`?

Comment: Do you really need growing delimiters around `\ce{...}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler approach with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\cebrack}{[}{]}
\NewDocumentCommand{\conc}{sO{}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\ensuremath{\cebrack*{\ce{#3}}}}
   {\ensuremath{\cebrack[#2]{\ce{#3}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
The molarity is calculated from \conc{NaOH}, \conc{H3O+}, and \conc{OH-}.

Test: \conc{H3O+}, \conc*{H3O+}, \conc[\big]{H3O+}, \conc[\Big]{H3O+}.

Test: $\conc{H3O+}, \conc*{H3O+}, \conc[\big]{H3O+}, \conc[\Big]{H3O+}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, this is, in my opinion, a legitimate usage of `\ensuremath`.

Comment: (Thanks, I mentioned `\ensuremath` largely due to your comments regarding its improper usage.) Does your code correctly account for the use of a star argument?

Comment: I'm thinking `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\ensuremath{\cebrack*{\ce{#3}}}}{\ensuremath{\cebrack[#2]{\ce{#3}}}}`, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @Anthony You're correct! I forgot the `*`. Fixed.